# How to add a outer tooltip in Angluar Sidebar?

Tags: java, html, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use a sidebar and want to add a tooltip. But everytime it is an "inner tooltip". i want to place it next to the sidebar.

[Sidebarclean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e31h6.png)

[Sidebarwithbrokentooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSdnH.png)

```
  <div class="app-sidebar-content">
    <div class="app-sidebar-scroll">
      <perfect-scrollbar [autoPropagation]="true" class="scroll-container" [scrollIndicators]="true"
        style="max-width: 600px; max-height: 600px">
        <!-- [config]="config" -->
        <div class="v-sidebar-menu vsm-default">
          <div class="vsm-list">
            <ngb-accordion [destroyOnHide]="false" [closeOthers]="true" [activeIds]="extraParameter">
              <ngb-panel id="dashboard">
                <ng-template ngbPanelHeader>
                  <button ngbPanelToggle class="vsm-link sidebar-menu-center " routerLink="/dasboard" >
                    <svg-icon key="home" fontSize="30px" ngbPopover="test" placement="right"></svg-icon>
                    <span class="vsm-title">Dashboard</span>
                  </button>
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel>
              <ngb-panel id="Kalendarium">
                <ng-template ngbPanelHeader>
                  <button ngbPanelToggle class="vsm-link sidebar-menu-center" routerLink="/calendar">
                    <svg-icon key="auswertungen" fontSize="30px"></svg-icon>
                    <span class="vsm-title">Kalendarium</span>
                  </button>
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel> -.........
```

how can i put the tooltext out of the sidebar? The tooltip should be shown if I hover the field / button / Menu.

Comment: The context needs to be more clear. In the above details, the sidebar should be in the left. So, you want the tooltip position left?
`placement="left"` will help you. If not, please update more details. A demo will be helpful.

Comment: i will try to setup a demo. I used ngbtooltip + position right as you can see in the source code. i but the  tooltip is still in the menu and not outside...